# Невидимые символы в textarea

Tags: html

Есть необходимость добавлять в текст, который отображается в `textarea`, служебные символы. Эти символы не должны быть видны пользователю.

Однако, любой HTML код, типа `&nbsp`; отображается в `textarea`  как есть. 
Управляющие символы типа `\n` и `\r` не видны, но приводят к переводу строки.

В итоге, пока нашел решение для IE - это символ `\b` и для Chrome - символ `\220`. Для FF пока решения нет. Есть ли универсальный невидимый символ для `textarea`, или  решение для Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Просто напиши фунцию перебора текста который в textarea?, например если в нем есть такой то символ вырезать его, либо же скрыть

что то вроде этого :

```
function validate(input) {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[\/\|\\?:<>"]/g, "");
}


<p>Проверочный текст: "Это проверочный текст" созданный 23/05/2018г. в 12:00?</p>
<textarea onkeyup="validate(this)" rows="5"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Это не то, что требуется. Мне нужны невидимые символы в поле textarea, которые стали бы видимыми при обработке  поля JS.

Comment: немного не понимаю, поставьте правильно вопрос.